# Windows 7 VLC command line problems

Tags: windows, vlc-media-player

I want a video to open, play and loop fullscreen automatically upon login. The following works when opening a cmd.exe window and typing it in:

```
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" file:///xmas.mp4 -f --loop
```

However, I have tried creating a shortcut, batch script, vbs script, scheduled task, EVERYTHING I can think of and it doesn't work. It appears to be launching VLC over and over and reports the following:

```
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///xmas.mp4". Check the log for details.
File reading failed:
VLC could not open the file "xmas.mp4". (%m)
```

And so on, over and over again, until I end the process.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: where on your filesystem does xmas.mp4 reside? is it your VLC install folder?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it in several locations, including the VLC install folder, root and \Users\myusername\

Comment: have you tried dropping the 'file:///'? I know VLC likes URIs but that should mean the file is in the system root (c:\). if you put the file in the root of C, does it work?

Comment: Have you tried using the full path to the file `xmas.mp4` in the place where you write `file:///`, plus using double quotes around it so that it doesn't escape off?

Answer (score 0):

It appears VLC cannot find the file you point to.

```
file:///xmas.mp4
```

`file://` is the "protocol" and the third slash is the root directory. So whatever your "root" directory is, `xmas.mp4` is not there.

For a fix, provide a full path to your file, e.g.:

```
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" file:///C:/myvideo/xmas.mp4 -f --loop
```

Tip: Unix-style paths don't work for VLC on Windows, but the `file://`-style path works.

Answer (score -1):

If the file is located in the root of C:

```
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" C:\xmas.mp4 -f --loop
```